# Filter object by keyname

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, filter

I have an object which I want to filter. This is what I use:

```
query = {
   "teststring-123": "true",
   "teststring-12344566": "false",
   test: "true"
}
```

I want to filter query so that after filtering I just have:

```
query = {
   "teststring-123": "true",
   "teststring-12344566": "false"
}

$(query).each(function(index, value) {
    $.each(value, function(i, v) {
        if(i.indexOf('teststring-')==-1) {
            // remove part of query object where index is this one       
            console.log(index)
        }
    });     
});
```

How can I handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) operator:

```
$.each(query, function(key, value) {
    if(key.indexOf('teststring-') == -1) {
        delete query[key];
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NvZyA/ (in this demo, [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) is used to show all keys).

Answer (score 3):

Are you trying to remove all key-value pairs that don't have keys starting with "teststring-"? If so...

```
for(var key in query){
    if(query.hasOwnProperty(key) && key.indexOf('teststring-') === -1){
        delete query[key];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for the [`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special_Operators/delete_Operator) operator.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) operator:

```
var query = {
   "teststring-123": "true",
   "teststring-12344566": "false",
   test: "true"
}
$.each(query, function(sKey) {
    if (sKey.indexOf("teststring-") < 0) { // or check if it is not on first position: != 0
        delete query[sKey];
    }  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As the others have said, use the `delete` operator. There is no need to iterate the object's properties however:

```
var query = {
    "teststring-123" : true,
    "teststring-12344566" :  false,
    test: true
};

delete query['test'];
```

Comment: The keys are not known beforehand. The OP wants to remove the keys which do not start with `"teststring*`.

Comment: yes, Rob W is right.. I do not know which other keys are present and need to filter all NOT starting with "teststring"..

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
var query = {
    "teststring-123": "true",
    "teststring-12344566": "false",
    "test": "true"
}
var newobj = {};

$.each(query, function(i, v) {
    if(i.indexOf('teststring-') != -1) {
        // remove part of query object where index is this one        
        console.log(i);
        newarr[i] = v;
    }
});
console.log(newobj);
```

Comment: Very good if the user is may using strict mode and it's included in a global plugin or something.